# Enzymes find('a') returns whole wrapper

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I will start from the beginning.
I have written some tests for a forgot password form. I have used enzyme, chai, sinon and some other things (see import list in included code).

The code for the form:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Form, Button, Input } from '@omnius/react-ui-elements';
import { resendPassword } from '../../actions/index';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';

const styles = {

  wrapper: {
    padding: '30px 20px',
    background: '#fff',
    borderRadius: '3px',
    border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
  },
  subTitle: {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
};

@connect(store => {
  return {
    config: store.config.components.Authentication,
    loading: store.authentication.forgotpassword_loading,
    errorMessage: store.authentication.forgotpassword_errorMessage,
    passwordSent: store.authentication.forgotpassword_passwordSent
  };
})

@translate(['authentication'], { wait: true })

class ForgotPassword extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: null
    };
    this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
  }

  handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(resendPassword(this.state.email));
  }

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;

    if(this.props.passwordSent) {
      return (
        <div style={styles.wrapper}>
          <h3>{t('Forgot password')}</h3>
          <p>{t('If an account is connected with the given email address, you will receive an email with a link to reset your password')}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Form style={styles.wrapper} onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
          <h3>{t('Forgot password')}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.errorMessage}</p>
          <Form.Field>
            <Input onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}  label={t('Email')}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <Button loading={this.props.loading} disabled={this.props.loading} type='submit' primary fluid>{t('Resend password')}</Button>
          </Form.Field>
        </Form>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default ForgotPassword;
```

The code for the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../../../src/i18n.js';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { ForgotPassword } from '../../../src';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import 'es6-promise/auto';
import sinon from 'sinon';

const initialConfig = {
  authentication: {
    loginform_loading: false,
    loginform_errorMessage: null,
    forgotpassword_loading: false,
    forgotpassword_errorMessage: null,
    forgotpassword_passwordSent: false
  },
  config: {
    components: {
      Authentication: {
        'login_endpoint': '/api/auth/login',
        'forgotpassword_enabled': true,
        'forgotpassword_path': '/auth/forgot-password',
        'forgotpassword_endpoint': '/auth/forgot-password'
      }
    }
  }
};
const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
let config;
let store;
let translator;
let context;
let HocElement;
let wrapper;

describe('components/ForgotPassword', () => {

  beforeEach(function () {
    config = clone(initialConfig);
    recreateWrapper();
  });

  function recreateWrapper(){
    store = mockStore(config);
    translator = createTranslator({});
    context = {
      i18n: translator
    };
    HocElement = translate(['authentication'], { nsMode: 'fallback' })(ForgotPassword);
    wrapper =  mount(<HocElement store={store} />, { context });
  }

  it('renders into DOM', () => {
    // Check whether the expected elements are rendered
    expect(wrapper.find('form')).to.have.length(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('h3')).to.have.length(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('p')).to.have.length(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('button')).to.have.length(1);
    expect(wrapper.find('input')).to.have.length(1);
    console.log(wrapper.find('a').html());
    expect(wrapper.find('a')).to.have.length(0);
  });

  it('should trigger the authentication method on form submit', () => {
    const callback = sinon.spy();
    const form = shallow(<ForgotPassword store={store} onSubmit={callback} />);

    // Submit isn't called yet so expected be not be called
    expect(callback.calledOnce).to.be.false;
    form.simulate('submit');

    // Submit is called so expected this to be true
    expect(callback.calledOnce).to.be.true;

    // Just another check to make sure the button isn't triggered to many times
    expect(callback.calledTwice).to.be.false;
  });
});

/**
 * Clones the given object, so it isn't linked to the original object.
 * @param objectToClone The object that will be cloned.
 * @return The cloned object.
 */
function clone(objectToClone){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToClone));
}

/**
 * Create a translator with the given translations
 * @param translations The translations
 * @return The translator
 */
function createTranslator(translations){
  const newI18n = i18n.createInstance();
  newI18n
    .init({
      lng: 'en',
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      resources: {
        en: translations
      },
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!
      }
    });
  return newI18n;
}
```

**The problem:**

In the 'renders into DOM' test there is an `expect(wrapper.find('a')).to.have.length(0);` this does however return false since there is some element found. It shows:

```
expected { Object (component, root, ...) } to have a length of 0 but got 1
```

Because of this I have added some logging: `console.log(wrapper.find('a').html());`
This logging outputs the following:

```
LOG: '<form class="ui form" style="padding: 30px 20px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid rgb(229, 229, 229); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><h3>Forgot password</h3><p></p><div class="field"><div class="ui labeled input ovn-ui-input"><div class="ui label label"><!-- react-text: 8 -->Email<!-- /react-text --></div><input type="text"></div></div><div class="field"><button type="submit" class="ui fluid primary button ovn-ui-button"><!-- react-text: 12 -->Resend password<!-- /react-text --></button></div></form>'
```

I have also tested this with having an `<a>hello</a>` in the form. In that case it returns 2 elements. With the first element being the form/wrapper and the second element being the actual `<a>`

**Summary**

When I search the wrapper with `.find('a')` it does somehow return the whole wrapper instead of nothing.

Comment: This might be because you're using enzyme's `mount()` method, which renders the whole DOM. Try using `shallow()`.

Comment: @JohnKennedy Tested this as you suggested it. Using `shallow()` instead of `mount()` causes the tests to return `expected { Object (root, unrendered, ...) } to have a length of 1 but got 0`. It seems like with shallow it is unable to find anything.

Comment: You're getting that because in shallow rendering most sub elements are not rendered to the DOM, it only tests what is mounted.

Comment: @JohnKennedy so this won't be the solution then. Since I need the full form to be loaded. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: In your component, are there any anchor tags? You're testing that it shouldn't find an `a` element which it is finding

Comment: @JohnKennedy Please see the included code of the form. This form **doesn't** have any anchor tags. That is the reason why it should return 0 elements. Also I have tested this with **one** anchor tag and then it returns **two** elements instead of **one**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153332/discussion-between-mrblueeyes-and-john-kennedy).